# United Kingdom Address Verification Web Service

Tags: service, verification, street-address

We're looking for a good web service or datasource that provides address verification for the United Kingdom. Was wondering if anyone else had used this type of product and had recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just after the pure data then you'll need this :

http://www2.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/postcode-address-file-paf?campaignid=paf_redirect

> The Postcode Address File (PAF®) is
>   the most up-to-date and complete
>   address database in the UK, containing
>   over 28 million addresses. PAF® is an
>   invaluable tool for creating and
>   maintaining mailing lists and
>   databases, as well as reducing the
>   number of returned or undelivered
>   items.
>
> PAF® is the only complete source of all known UK Postcodes.

If you want a software frontend to it included then there's [this](http://www.afd.co.uk/). I've not used it for a couple of years but I don't think it had a webservice aspect.

Postcode information in the UK is owned by the Post Office and not free, easily running into tens of thousands depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[Satori Software](http://www.satorisoftware.com) offer a number of address and post code checking products (for the UK and other counties) including one that we use to check addresses in web submitted data via a java stored procedure in an Oracle database.  This is also used to provide address lookup for UK postcodes.  It works well enough and is pretty simple to integrate.

They license the data from the various national postal services themselves.